# Is "trees of green" same as "green trees"?

Tags: grammar

For example in the song "What A Wonderful World", Louis Armstrong says:

> I see trees of green, red roses, too, I see them bloom, for me and
>   you. And I think to myself, What a wonderful world.

That was always a question for me.

Comment: "trees of green" is a hackneyed poeticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it means something like "green trees".  Green is the color of the trees.  This isn't how people normally talk, but it's understandable and sounds rather poetic.

I can only guess why Bob Thiele wrote what he did, but I would be surprised if the *sound* of the words wasn't a major consideration.